# The number of independent components of an antisymmetric rank five tensor in 3-D space

Tags: tensors

The question I'm trying to answer is this:

> $T_{ijklm}$ is anti-symmetric with respect to all pairs of indices. How many independent components does it have in 3-D space?

I'm not looking for the answer, but I would appreciate a little help on how I can do this.

Comment: I do know that the number of _total_ indicies of given by $D^n$, and that the anti symmetry will contract the number of independent components, I just don't know how to go about showing that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if two of $i, j, k, l, m$ are the same $T_{ijklm} = 0$. Can you have five distinct indices if $T$ is a tensor on $\mathbb{R}^3$?